# create list from xml file c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am getting this rss feeds and i am trying to get the data of the rss feed to a list format so that my customers can search through the data.

this is the ONLY way that worked for this kind of xml data:

```
xmlFile.SelectNodes("//ns:id |//ns:title | //ns:description", xmlnm);

public void MyMain(string[] args)
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("url to xml file");
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDocument.Load(dataStream);
    XmlNamespaceManager xmlnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
    xmlnm.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

    ParseXML(xmlDocument, xmlnm);

    MessageBox.Show("\n---XML parsed---");
    //Console.ReadKey();
}

public void ParseXML(XmlDocument xmlFile, XmlNamespaceManager xmlnm)
{
    //this commented section WORKS FANTASTIC!!
    /* XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//ns:id |//ns:title | //ns:description", xmlnm);;
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(node.Name + " = " + node.InnerXml);
    }
    */

    //SO i decided to store the xml data into a list, and nothing works below. I have a created a simple RSSXML class to store the information
    XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//ns:id |//ns:title | //ns:description", xmlnm);
    List<RSSXML> items = new List<RSSXML>();           
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        items.Select(x => new RSSXML()
        {
            id = node.InnerXml,
            title = node.InnerXml,
            description = node.InnerXml,
            //can add more fields here
        }).ToList();             

    }
    foreach (var myitems in items)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(myitems.summary.ToString());
    }
}

public class RSSXML()
{
//simple get set methods for id, title, description, etc
}
```

Comment: can you give a sample xml?  and does your `nodes` variable have the correct data in it? In your Object Initializer, you are assigning all properties the same value, `node.InnerXml` which doesn't make sense

Comment: `and nothing works below` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`items.Select()` produces a new List, you are not storing it.

The basic fix:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//ns:id |//ns:title | //ns:description", xmlnm);
List<RSSXML> items = new List<RSSXML>();           
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    //items.Select(x => new RSSXML()
    items.Add(new RSSXML {
    {
        id = node.InnerXml,
        title = node.InnerXml,
        description = node.InnerXml,
        //can add more fields here
    //}).ToList();             
    });
}
```

You could eliminate the foreach() :

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlFile.SelectNodes("//ns:id |//ns:title | //ns:description", xmlnm);
List<RSSXML> items = nodes.Select(n => new RSSXML()
    {
        id = n.InnerXml,
        title = n.InnerXml,
        description = n.InnerXml,
        //can add more fields here
    }).ToList();
```

And you probably want to replace `.InnerXml` with just `.Value`.

Comment: I could eliminate foreach, and will it then store the whole entry for that xml tag?

Comment: excellent this works, the only thing is, will it match it as a key/value pair or it is just one big dump of lists?

Comment: `item` is not a "dump of lists" but 1 single list. Which should work for a ListBox or DataGrid.

Comment: the reason why i asked is, each id has its own title and description, so if i am storing it like this, and i loop through it, can i easily grab title/description based on an ide?

Comment: Yes, and again without a loop: `var item = items.Single(it => it.id == myId)`